# Rotating map control in direction of travel, Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I count the route and watch the user's current location and when it begins to move, I want rotate map in direction of travel. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance! And sorry for my bad English ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can literally apply a RotateTransform to the map control and use the Compass sensor (magnetometer) to get the direction of travel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202974(v=vs.105).aspx

Please read the "Determining the Compass Orientation Mode" section of the above link.